# How to declare the KeyEventArgs from different HeaderFile Class?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a HeaderFile Common_Datas.h

```
//Common_Datas.h

public ref class MyDBDatas
{
//blah...blah...blah...

public: static System::Void Material_Name( System::Object^ Sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^ e) {
//blah...blah...blah...
}

public: static System::Void Supplier_Name( System::Object^ Sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^ e) {
//blah...blah...blah...
}
};
```

And now from my Form2 - textBox2 I would like to declare

```
textBox2->KeyDown += gcnew KeyEventHandler(MyDBDatas, &MyDBDatas::Supplier_Name);
```

1. Iam not getting the above line........
2. Also I would like to learn same statement, how to use in "delegate" statemen?

   Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in the delegate constructor is the object, not the type, that the delegate should be called on. Try this in the MyDBDatas constructor:

```
MyDBDatas()
{
    textBox2->KeyDown += gcnew KeyEventHandler(this, &MyDBDatas::Supplier_Name);
}                                              ^^^^
```

Comment: Hi David, Showing 4 - Errors 01. C2143 Syntax error: missing ';' before '}'

Comment: 02.Errors C3350 KeyEventHandler : adelegate constructor expects 1-arguments

Comment: Those two errors are probably a simple typo, a missing parentheses or semicolon or something like that.